# Converting the Great Circle distance to direct distance between two points on earth?

Tags: geometry, circles

Apologies if this question has been asked before.

Across the surface of the Earth, the distance between London and New York is 5567 km. Given that the earth has a radius of 6371 km, what is the distance between London and New York, supposing a path between them was dug through the earth's crust?

I am interested because I would like to know the minimum theoretical latency for data transmission between the two cities (given the speed of light), but I don't know how to calculate it myself. (I made an attempt and got 9770km, which is obviously wrong...)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would you achieve the speed of light a few hundred kilometers beneath the surface?

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake Assuming sufficiently high technology, perhaps a neutrino emitter and detector? Or a cable coated in some kind of super-insulator.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. One more thing, that will help provide an answer. Can you assume as a satisfactory approximation that Earth is a sphere? (Because in reality it is not as you surely know). If we make that assumption I think it is easy to solve it.

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake I think it's OK to make that approximation, given that the error bounds are known: "The errors introduced by assuming a spherical Earth based on the international nautical mile are not more than 0.5% for latitude, 0.2% for longitude." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance#cite_note-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means $\theta$, your angle between lines extending from Earth's centre to London and New York, is equal to $\frac{5567}{6371}=0.8738$ radians.

Now let's construct a triangle with your proposed tunnel, the radius from Earth's centre to NY, and from Earth's centre to London. The angles in a triangle add to $\pi$ radians, and since two of the legs of the triangle (the two radii) are the same, we know the two remaining angles are the same. Thus, $\frac{\pi-0.8738}{2}=1.1339$ is the measure of the other two angles.

Using law of sines and letting $x$ be the length between NY and London:

$$\frac{\sin1.1339}{6371}=\frac{\sin0.8738}{x}$$

$$x=\frac{6371\sin0.8738}{\sin1.1339}=5391.5475$$

So the distance between New York and London is $5391.5475$ km.

[image]

Comment: Supporting image added.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By the way, building the tunnel saves about 0.5ms of latency (~18.5ms vs 18ms). Given that current transmission latencies are around ~30ms, I think there is other low hanging fruit we can tackle first!

Comment: Is that significant?

Comment: In the field of high frequency trading, I think it will be significant one day.

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Comment: I do think you need to worry about how hot it is down there. The deepest point of your straight line is about 600km down, and the temperature that deep  seems to be about 1700 or 1800 K, say 1450°C or 2600°F. Check the article on Geothermal gradient.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a simple function that will provide the answer given the great circle distance as input, the following is adequate:

```
def through_crust_distance(sphere_dist):
    return ( 6378*sin(sphere_dist/6378) ) / sin( (math.pi-(sphere_dist/6378)) / 2 )
```

Comment: + for giving a closed formula of sphere_dist. That's exactly what was actually requested.

Answer (score 1):

We assume that Earth is a sphere of radius $r$ and consider an intersection of it to help our intuition.

Let $A,B$ be two points on the surface of the Earth. Then we can consider them as points that lie on a circle with radius $r$. The distance between them is the arc length $\theta r$, where $\theta$ is the angle $AKB$, where $K$ denotes the center of the Earth, and thus the center of the circle.

We are interested in evaluating the direct distance $AB$. This is equal to the length of the chord $AB$. Let it be equal to $c$.

Since $AKB$ is an isosceles triangle, by the law of cosines we have that 
$$\cos \theta=1-\frac{c^2}{2r^2}\Rightarrow\\c^2=2r^2(1-\cos\theta)$$

Since we know $\theta,r$ we evaluate $c$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it makes it clearer. I computed the equation and got 5391km.

Comment: @Oliver Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need the Law of Sines or the Law of Cosines.

If the vertex angle is $\theta$, just draw the perpendicular bisector, and see that the base of your isosceles triangle is $2r\sin(\theta/2)$.